# If I group in Crystal Reports to get the distinct records, my total varies

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

My situation is almost like this [link](http://businessintelligence.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/businessobjects-crystal-l/how-to-select-a-distinct-record-in-crystal-reports-85-2054261).

I grouped and suppressed the detail and displayed result on group header, but **@total** is summing all records rather summing the distinct one's .

Please suggest how to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming group 4 is the distinctly selected group, it should work with a running total.  Set the `Summary` field to the field you are totaling, the `Evaluate` option to `On change of group` (selecting group 4), and `Reset` to `Never`.

If you need to pull distinct records that are not grouped in group 4 (or one of the other groups), then you would probably have to write a running total manually.  Then, you can use whatever logic makes sense for when to add to the total.

If they are not in any set order, you would have to be fancier, I'd personally use an array to keep track of which records have been added to the total.  If a record is in the array, don't do anything, and if it isn't, add to the total and then add the record to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want total of each group..?? If yes then then try placing your **@total** in that group footer section not in Report Footer

Comment: i do not want group total, i want report total.